# OS X copy directories and files with space

Tags: macos, copy

I am newbie to OS X and please don't ignore if this is too basic. Direct me as required I am trying to copy directory(from by old external hard drive) with lots of files on to local mac machine(say: ~/Desktop/Copy). ***I have lots of sub directories and files with spaces.*** i was using this command

> `cp -R /Volumes/My\ Passport/Directory1 ~/Desktop/Copy`

I see lots of errors saying *'No such file or directory'*, first i thought it's some issue with the files and later found that its because of spaces in the file names. Can anyone suggest me a good way to address this issue.  I try to use rsync but its taking long time in building the list and its taking for ever.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spaces in the file names should not be an issue. Perhaps you can paste the error message? When using `cp` for your task, you probably want to use the `-p` option.

Comment: Looks like the issue is Permissions. Since MyPassport was used on windows and when connected to mac its just readonly. When i run cp command, it even copied the permissions as well, so that destination directory also became readonly.   Error which i am seeing is: ** cp: /Users/TestUser/Desktop/Office-D/CMS/AMD_VGA/SG/msvcr80.dll: Permission denied**

Answer (score 0):

For help with the `cp` command, or any command, do `man cp`, or in general `man command_name`

If you want to copy everything, you could do

```
cp -R /Volumes/My\ Passport/ ~/Desktop/Copy/
```

Which would copy the content of `My Passport` to a directory called `Copy`.

If you want to copy only specific files, say directories only,

```
cp -R `ls -p /Volumes/My\ Passport/ | grep /` ~/Desktop/Copy/
```

If you want to copy only files

```
cp -R `ls -p /Volumes/My\ Passport/ | grep -v /` ~/Desktop/Copy/
```

If you want to copy files or directories with specific names

```
cp -R /Volumes/My\ Passport/*.jpg ~/Desktop/Copy/   # copy only jpg files
                            *.txt                   # copy only txt files
                            Vacation-2015-*         # copy files or dir that have the prefix 'Vaction-2015-'
                            *2015.jpg               # copy files with postfix '2015.jpg'
```

Comment: The plain `cp` commands will work fine, as will the ones that use wildcards to get file lists, but all of the commands using `ls ...` to get a list of files will fail on files with spaces (and some other metacharacters) in their names. See ["Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).